# Закрученные(,) как у барана(,) рога. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

**От других драконов его отличали закрученные(,) как у барана(,) рога.**
Нужны ли указанные запятые? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Надеюсь, я не испортила Вашу правку.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, все в порядке. Вы улучшили оформление вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**От других драконов его отличали закрученные как у барана рога.**

Я бы не стала ставить запятые, основываясь вот на этом правиле.

Обороты с союзом **как** не выделяются запятыми, если на первый план в обороте выступает значение **обстоятельства образа действия**, отвечающее на вопрос "*как?*".
Обычно такие обороты можно заменить творительным падежом существительного или наречием.

***Как град*** посыпалась картечь (Лермонтов). — Посыпалась **градом.**
***Как демон*** коварна и зла (Лермонтов). — **Демонически** коварна.

[Запятая перед союзом "КАК"](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/317-zapyatayaperedsyuzomkak.html)

Закрученные (как?) как у барана = по-бараньи.
Можно перестроить предложение, тогда четко будет видно, что запятые не нужны.
*От других драконов его отличали рога, **закрученные как у барана*** [по-бараньи].